# Prestashop Product condition in order Email

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to show product condition in mails/en/**order_conf_product_list.tpl**

I tried adding

```
{$product['condition']}
```

but i get this error:

*Notice: Undefined index: condition in /home/yourserver/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 70*

I guess I must make modification of mailalerts.php, but how to get the product condition?

Comment: $product does not contain an array key of 'condition'. `var_dump()` it and see what it does have.

Comment: I did {$product|@var_dump} as debloy1978uk suggested and this is the result it looks like condition is not in that array: array(6) { 
["reference"]=> string(2) "10" 
["name"]=> string(35) "test" 
["unit_price"]=> string(9) "45,00 $" 
["price"]=> string(9) "45,00 $" 
["quantity"]=> int(1) 
["customization"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: I tried to search the class file or control file but I cant get the right file to make the modification so that i can get also condition in $product array

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by myself so in case anyone face same problem:

For Prestashop: 1.6~

1. edit classes/PaymentModule.php after line 467 add:

   'condition' => $product['condition'],
2. In your email template the file "order_conf_product_list.tpl" use:

   {$product['condition']}